# Testing private static generic methods in C#

Tags: c#, generics, testing, methods, static

How does one test private static generic methods?  The internals are visible to my test project.  How can one test these methods?

```
internal class Foo {

    // Non-static.  This works!
    private T TestThisMethod1<T>(T value) {
        Console.WriteLine("Called TestThisMethod1");
        return value;
    }

    // Static.  Can't get this to work!
    private static T TestThisMethod2<T>(T value) {
        Console.WriteLine("Called TestThisMethod2");
        return value;
    }

    // Static.  Can't get this to work!
    private static void TestThisMethod3<T>(T value) {
        Console.WriteLine("Called TestThisMethod3");
    }

    // Static.  Can't get this to work!
    private static void TestThisMethod4<T, T2>(T value, T2 value2) {
        Console.WriteLine("Called TestThisMethod4");
    }
}
```

The first example works.  It's not static.  It's the example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546207.aspx.

```
[TestMethod]
public void PrivateStaticGenericMethodTest() {

    int value = 40;
    var foo = new Foo();

    // This works.  It's not static though.
    PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject(foo);
    int result1 = (int)privateObject.Invoke("TestThisMethod1", new Type[] { typeof(int) }, new Object[] { value }, new Type[] { typeof(int) });

    // Fails
    int result2 = (int)privateObject.Invoke("TestThisMethod2",  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, new Type[] { typeof(int) }, new Object[] { value }, new Type[] { typeof(int) });

    // Fails
    PrivateType privateType = new PrivateType(typeof(Foo));
    int result2_1 = (int)privateType.InvokeStatic("TestThisMethod2", new Type[] { typeof(int) }, new Object[] { value }, new Type[] { typeof(int) });

    // Fails
    int result2_2 = (int)privateType.InvokeStatic("TestThisMethod2", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, new Type[] { typeof(int) }, new Object[] { value }, new Type[] { typeof(int) });

    // Stopping here.  I can't even get TestThisMethod2 to work...
}
```

My purpose in writing is not really to question or debate the merits of testing private methods: That subjected has been debated over and over.  More so, my purpose in writing the question is to say "It should be possible to do this using PrivateObject or PrivateType.  So, how can it be done?"

Comment: Do you have any consumers of your private static method? If no, then why test its behavior?

Comment: Generally private methods are tested through the public methods that call them

Comment: True, I usually follow the norm of "Only test public methods".  These days, I hate to make anything publicly accessible if I can avoid it.  This method is buried very deep in the code.  I should be able to test this method in isolation with either PrivateObject or PrivateType.

Comment: The generic T items are the issue.  With those it cannot find the method for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found a way to do this with google searching for testing with generic types.  Using the object its self request the method then run through the make generic method call and lastly invoke it.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    int value = 40;
    var foo = new Foo();

    MethodInfo fooMethod = foo.GetType().GetMethod("TestThisMethod2", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fooMethod == null)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Could not find method");
    }
    MethodInfo genericFooMethod = fooMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
    int result1 = (int)genericFooMethod.Invoke(typeof(int), new object[] { value });

    Assert.AreEqual(result1, value);
}
```

Comment: This is a solution and it does answer the question.  

I was expecting that PrivateObject or PrivateType could do this behind the scenes without performing reflection myself though.  Unfortunately, it appears that neither will work in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 5):

You are not supposed to test private methods. Because they are an implementation detail that can change. You are supposed to test your public interface.

If you have private methods that are not covered after you have covered your public interface, delete them.

Comment: I would not always subscribe to a hard and fast rule "You are not supposed to test private methods."

Suppose you had a complex console app with only a public entry point, would you not test anything?  I would not want to change the accessibility of a method just because I want to test it.

Comment: If your Console app is not modular enough and has only it's main as a public entry point, it's either a quick hack for something that's not worth writing unit tests for... or it's a substandard software design. The Console app is the UI... your business and data layers should not be private methods.

Comment: The console app was just an example....  My intent is not to debate the value of testing private methods or not.

Microsoft saw value in creating the PrivateObject and PrivateType classes to test private methods.  I am seeking to understand how to use them correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Through my tests, PrivateObject seems to have problems with static and generic methods.  piggy backing on Brian's answer, here is a method you can use (and modify).

```
public static class PrivateMethodTester
{
    public static object InvokePrivateMethodWithReturnType<T>(T testObject, string methodName, BindingFlags flags, Type[] genericTypes, object[] parameters) {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = testObject.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, flags);
        if (methodInfo == null) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to find method.");
        }
        MethodInfo method = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypes);
        return method.Invoke(genericTypes, parameters);
    } 
}
```

Call it like this:

```
            Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(MyGenericType1) };
            var parameters = new object[] { new MyClassParam(), "stringParam" };
            var returnObj = PrivateMethodTester.InvokePrivateMethodWithReturnType(new TestObjectClass("fake", null), "MyPrivateMethodName", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, types, parameters);
```